# Using await inside node global scope to load db client possible?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to use the `pg`, a Postgres client for Node. In the examples, it uses the following code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client()

await client.connect()

const res = await client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'])
console.log(res.rows[0].message) // Hello world!
await client.end()
```

I understand the async/await function syntax requires that you write await statements within functions that are declared as async. However, typically when you connect a database client, you connect it outside of functions and in the global scope. Are there any best practices to using the async function without having to wrap the client inside a function?

It seems that to use this syntax, we'd have to resort to something like the following:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const client = new Client();

async connectClient (client) { 
   await client.connect();
   return client;
}

async disconnectClient(client) {
  await client.end()
}
```

Perhaps I'm missing something in my understanding here.

Comment: Verify the solution if it worked for you. @steviejay

Comment: @GökcanD the solution works for sure, but i'd like to see if there are other alternatives still; particularly without having to resort to the OOP Design elements

Answer (score 1):

> However, typically when you connect a database client, you connect it outside of functions and in the global scope. Are there any best practices..?

You may use **Connection Pooling** technique

For the sake of best practices of using the connection pooling. Try to implement OOP design elements in your application. Such as classes and inheritance.

**Service.ts**

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

export class Service {
  protected pool: Pool;

  constructor() {
    this.pool = new Pool({
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
    });
  }
```

Example service class that extends base class `Service`:

**AuthnService.ts**

```
export class AuthService extends Service {
  private key: string;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.key = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
  }
  // Example async function that shows the usage of pg with async/await
  public async isUserExists(username: string, email?: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const client = await this.pool.connect(); //Pool is now accessible over here
    try {
      let res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1', [ username ]);
      if (res.rows[0]) {
        return res.rows[0];
      } else if (email) {
        res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1', [ email ]);
        if (res.rows[0]) {
          return res.rows[0];
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      client.release(); // Release for other connections to use
    }
    return false;
      }
  }
}
```

More information: [node-postgres docs](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling)